# Good practice to use guard/if-statements to style multiple CollectionvViewCells?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a dilemma where I have in my `CollectionView` each `collectionviewcell` is displaying different data and have different border/background styles to them. for example, a code snippet

```
let monsters: Monsters!


    cell.graphViewIBO.isHidden = true
    cell.monsblIBO.isHidden = true
    cell.powersBgIBO.isHidden = true


    guard indexPath.row != 0 else {

        cell.indexOne(monsters)
        return cell
    }
    guard indexPath.row != 1 else {

        cell.indexTwo(monsters)
        return cell
    }
    guard indexPath.row != 2 else {

        cell.indexThree(monsters)
        return cell
    }
```

I feel like this may be bad practice and am uncertain whether I should continue doing it this way, or just use a `scrollview` and style each `uiview` in it independently. 
Because as of right my storyboard contains several objects in one `collectionviewcell` that I need to hide/show depending on which index is being presented. Can I continue using a CollectionView for this? What method is the right method for this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to use is a `switch` statement. Your code would look as follows:

```
let monsters: Monsters!

cell.graphViewIBO.isHidden = true
cell.monsblIBO.isHidden = true
cell.powersBgIBO.isHidden = true

switch indexPath.row {
case 0:
    cell.indexOne(monsters)
case 1:
    cell.indexTwo(monsters)
case 2:
    cell.indexThree(monsters)
default: break
}

return cell
```

If you are changing your cells a lot, you can create different subclasses of `UICollectionViewCell`, which you create depending on which index. If you are using each type of cell only once, a UIScrollView would be better. But if you are using the same type of cell more than once (and just change some text for example), you should use a UICollectionView.

Comment: Each cell has a styling unique to its indexPath. So that would mean a uiscrollview would be a better approach?

Comment: If the styling difference is just a different color or font, you're probably fine using a `UICollectionView`, but if the styling also means view positioning and number of views visible I would use a UIScrollView.